# I can't create my database in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using WAMP and have written a php script to connect to the data base i don't think it's the code because i'm getting an error that says `SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for` and then get several different errors, some say :

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\php.php

Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=9044 in C:\wamp\www\php.php

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\php.php
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:80",'user','');
if(!$con){
    die( 'error:' . mysql_error());
}
$db = 'CREATE DATABASE db_one';
if(mysql_query($db,$con)){
    echo 'data base created';
}
else {
    echo 'Err:' . mysql_error();
}
$table = 'CREATE TABLE persons ( fname varchar (15),lname varchar(15), age int)';
mysql_query($table,$con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What did you say to make it go away?

Comment: Have you started the mysql service?

Comment: @user1867842 the code should be in the question, not in the comment...

Comment: yes it is started ? do i use the console for mysql ? i tried using phpmyadmin but it doesn't let me use it. It says something about mysqli extension missing and i've commented out the comment with the ";" i took out. And also removed the path variable for PHPRC

Comment: Port 80 is wrong.. and the 'create table' statement won't default to your new db. Add it as 'db_one.persons'

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the port declaration from the connection.

```
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1",'user','');
```

Or change it to 3306 (default for mysql)

Comment: i tried it and got an error  >>>>  Err:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.persons' at line 1

Comment: Right, which means your connection is now working... now fix your SQL :)

Comment: and if i remove the '.persons' i get this error >>>> Err:Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_one'

Comment: Well, it looks like you have created a database, but have not set any permissions for it. If the account you are connecting with is not a root level account, it is most likely not granted rights on the new database.

Comment: I fixed your initial errors. We're now on to a new topic. On a side note, you should always try to run the queries with something like phpmyadmin to see if they do what you want, how you want.

Comment: okay i got it i just needed to open up the mysql console and type in create user 'name'@'127.0.0.1' and then hit enter and then type in grant all privileges on *.* to 'name'@'127.0.0.1' and then hit enter and ran my code refreshed the browser and it said 'database created'

Comment: Click the check mark under the vote arrows on the correct answer